# Blob export not working in safari

Tags: javascript, ios, svg, safari, blob

I want to export the jpeg image from svg using blob. This working fine in chrome. But, my sample is not working safari browser(MAC).
Can you please tell how to resolve this? wheather blob is support in IOS or not?
while run this sample in ios thrown image load error.

Sample Link: http://jsfiddle.net/kyjs655r/363/

```
document.getElementById('export').onclick = function () {
            var tag = document.getElementById('export');
            tag.download = 'Sample' + "." + 'png';
            tag.href = getCanvaElement().toDataURL();
        }

        function getCanvaElement() {
            var svgText = document.getElementById("myViewer").outerHTML;
            var svg = new Blob([svgText], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });
            var domURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
            var url = domURL.createObjectURL(svg);
            var element = document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx = element.getContext("2d");
            var image = new Image;
            image.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                domURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            };
            image.onerror = function () {
                alert();
            };
            image.src = url;
            return element;
        }
```

Comment: `Blob` is defined at Safari 8+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob. Can you describe the different outputs that you get at different browsers?

Comment: in that same sample check in chrome in windows. it will work but in IOS image.onload event is not triggered that's the lack.

Comment: Have not tried ios, not able to reproduce the issue that you describe. What is the purpose of ` || self`?

Comment: A few problems, Safari doesn't like you set the charset in the MIMEType, and laoding an image is async => By the time you call toDataURL the canvas element may still be empty.